# Where do I put the list of deliberately misspelled words to be ignored by lint?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code, lint, spell-checking

I am working on a react/node project with VSCode. It has a linter that underlines misspelled words. Where do I put the list of words that are deliberately misspelled so that the linter will ignore it?

Answer (score 1):

Found it. It is under `.vscode/settings.json`. Add:

```
{
  "cSpell.ignoreWords": ["topbar", "redir"]
}
```